# cassandra titan keyspce format changed

Tags: cassandra

My keyspace directory in cassandra has changed.

Before there were names like **/titan/edgestore**
Now the names have been replaced by **/titan/edgestore-666f1c30890f11e4a226bf0df252193b** 
and another directory has spawned: **/titan/edgestore_lock_-667a18b0890f11e4a226bf0df252193b**.

I don't know what happened. It works when I load cassandra on my computer, but when I make a snapshot and send it to another computer, the other cassandra can't reload the snapshot.

I use cassandra 2.1.2 and titan 0.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The hashed data directory structure is a new feature in Cassandra 2.1:

- https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/NEWS.txt#L53-L58
- https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/CHANGES.txt#L791-L792
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202